# Large amount of text not rendering properly in a scroll view - React Native

Tags: react-native

Hi so I've got a ToC section in my app that I want to present in a scrollview.

```
<ScrollView style={{ height: 400 }}>
  <Text>{data[0].toc}</Text>
</ScrollView>
```

When it renders it displays the following:
[image: Simulator not rendering text properly]

Is this a problem caused by how I'm rendering these elements or Is there a more efficient way to render large amounts of text similar to how a list view works for example?

Comment: Try giving your text a style with a height

Comment: Try to add `flex: 1` to your style and remove the explicit `height: 400`

Comment: so it renders if I assign a height to the Text tag, however I can only assign a height of 8000. Anything over then 8000 I get the same rendering issue. Any idea how to reslove this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got the same problem and here is a solution. Try to separate large `<Text>` component into several smaller `<Text>` components. It worked for me. I had to show ToS in the app and it did not render well, because the text was too big and I wrapped it in only one `<Text>` tag. After brainstorm with my colleagues we decided to try to separate text into several `<Text>` components and it worked.